# Function from imported class is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set up an app using ES6 classes for the first time, but having difficulty calling a function from an imported class.

The Class to be imported:

```
import {BaseElement} from './ui/base-element.js';

export class Product extends BaseElement {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.toggleAttributes();
}

// show more attributes toggle
toggleAttiributes () {
    const toggleButton = document.querySelectorAll('.smrt42-toggle-attr')
    document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        const t = e.target;
        if(t.className.indexOf('smrt42-toggle-attr') !== -1) {
            e.preventDefault()
            let productAttrs = t.parentNode.previousElementSibling
            if(t.classList.contains('smrt42-toggle-attr-more')) {
                productAttrs.classList.add('smrt42-attr-open')
            } else if (t.classList.contains('smrt42-toggle-attr-less')) {
                productAttrs.classList.remove('smrt42-attr-open')
            }
        }

    })
}
}
```

Importing the Class here:

```
import {BaseElement} from './ui/base-element.js';
import {Product} from './product.js';

export class Content extends BaseElement {

constructor() {
    super()
       let p = new Product() ;
    }
}
```

This gives a console error `this.toggleAttributes is not a function`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan in the `Product` class's constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistyped the name of the function. In declaration you have the name `toggleAttiributes`, but you call it as `toggleAttributes`. Extra `i` is here

```
toggleAttiributes
---------^-------
```

Comment: We have a close reason for such questions. A comment is more than enough in such a case.

Comment: I can't believe it... but actually I can.